# How to import the .js file in .scss file

Tags: javascript, sass

I am doing white label angular web application. Is it possible to import my config.js file in header.scss file?

I tried to import it like this in my header.scss file:

```
@import '../../mixins.scss';
@import { themeColor } '../../config';

header{background-color: themeColor.backgroundColor; color:themeColor.color}
```

My config file:

```
export const themeColor = (buttonColor, textColor) =>({
    backgroundColor: buttonColor,
    color:textColor
})
```

However, I'm getting an error. How do I import it correctly?

Comment: why dont you use `mixins` in sass.

Comment: @manishkumar thanks for reply can you please explain how to do?

Comment: Have a look at this blog entry: https://itnext.io/sharing-variables-between-js-and-sass-using-webpack-sass-loader-713f51fa7fa0

Comment: @achu simply looking for "mixins sass" on google gave [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-sass-mixins). Once you've been directed to a term to look for you should look for it *before* asking further questions that are easily answerable by searching.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca When loading my web application from the URL I get the background-color and color how I will pass the value to `mixins`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Sass has no mechanism for handling JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `node-sass-json-importer`.

It's an old library but it's 2023 and I keep importing js variables into my sass files with this tool. I do it with nextjs and vite projects.

My vite config file:

```js
import jsonImporter from "node-sass-json-importer"
...

export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        importer: jsonImporter(),
      }
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

My nextjs config file:

```js
import jsonImporter from "node-sass-json-importer"
...

const baseConfig = {
  sassOptions: {
    importer: jsonImporter(),
  },
  ...
}

...
```